# WIndows 8 apps launch an app within the frame of another app

Tags: windows-8

I need to launch an app within the frame of another app. I tried implementing the activatoin protocol. it works fine except it launches the second app as another app but not within the frame of the first app. what I want to be able to do is launch app2 within the frame of a page in app1 and be able to use the back button to go back to app1.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on Windows 8. Apps can't launch other apps within them.

What was it that are you trying to do? Authentication? Maybe you can do something like oauth?

Comment: No.. I have a suite of applications around 50.Sometimes there is a link between the apps for example App1 is for a certain purpose but it displays a bunch of objects in one of hte screens and there is a whole new application App2 that does different functionality for that object. Its not manageable to have 50 apps in one app but for ease of opening applications with the selected object, it makes sense to be able to launch App2 when user clicks on the object and chooses to view details displayed in App2.